# Ghostscript doesn't keep landscape page orientation

Tags: ghostscript

Example:
Create a one sheet landscape PDF from Excel. Open it using Adobe Reader, where it opens as landscape. Print it using Ghostscript. Open printout using Adobe Reader, and it should still be landscape, but it isn't.

This issues happens whether or not the source is a PDF or Excel itself. I use a PDF source in the example because I figured that it would be easier to illustrate the issue.

I know it can probably be forced to be printed using landscape. What I don't understand is why Ghostscript is not using the orientation of the original document. How can I get Ghostscript to keep the orientation of the original document?

PDFWrite config file:

`-I"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.22\lib";"C:\Program Files\gs\fonts"
 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite
 -r300
 -dNOPAUSE
 -dSAFER
 -sPAPERSIZE=A4
 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4
 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress`

Redmon config:

`@"C:\Program Files\gs\pdfwrite.txt" -sOutputFile="%1" -c 30000000 setvmthreshold .setpdfwrite -f -`

Printer driver:

Ghostscript PDF

Answer (score 4):

You've left the `AutoRotatePages` switch at the default. The default is to rotate pages so that the majority of text is horizontal, if you don't want that, then set `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`.

Since you apparently already have a PDF file ? Why use Ghostscript to create another one ? You stand the chance of losing stuff that way.

Since the input is PDF there is no point in the -sPAPERSIZE switch, since that only sets the dfefault media, which is immediately overridden by the PDF interpreter.

If I were you I wouldn't set -dPDFSETTINGS at all, nor -r300 (the resolution setting is mostly pointless for pdfwrite)

Comment: I set dAutoRotatePages and removed dPDFSETTINGS and r300. However, the printout still comes out as portrait.

Comment: This issues happens whether or not the source is PDF or actual Microsoft Excel. I used a PDF source because I figured that it would be easier to illustrate the issue. Good point on not converting PDFs.

Comment: An important note: my printer driver is Ghostscript PDF.

Comment: You're going to have to make an example available then, nothing I can do otherwise. Note also that if you are taking the PDF file and **printing** it to get a new PDF file, then you have to take the printing system into account and **that** may be where the re-orientation comes in. I was assuming you were using Ghostscript directly. You can set the 'print to file' option to get the PostScript before it is converted to PDF. My bet is that its the printing system.