# Ghostscript is not printing according the page orientaion

Tags: command-line, printing, ghostscript

I am using the ghostscript command to print a pdf file to a printer.

If the pdf has some pages landscape and some portrait - it prints them all in portrait.

When I take the same pdf and do print from the Adobe reader - it prints correctly.

I tried this thread:

[Ghostscript doesn't keep landscape page orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865033/ghostscript-doesnt-keep-landscape-page-orientation)

but got the same result..

The command is:

```
gswin64c.exe -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="%printer%HP Officejet 4500 G510g-m" "myFile.pdf"
```

and I tried the next options as well

```
 -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sPAPERSIZE=legal
```

-dORIENT1=false 
 -dAutoRotatePages=/None

Comment: > I am using the ghostscript command

**What** Ghostscript command ? You haven't given a Ghostscript command line, and you haven't supplied an example input file.

Are you suggesting that your printer has both portrait and landscape media available ?

Without knowing a great deal more about your problem, there's not anything anyone can do to help.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

So you are using the mswinpr2 device. While useful, the device has some limitations, and I think you have (possibly) come across one of them.

The device works by having Ghostscript render the input to a bitmap, which it then blits into a device context derived from the printer device. The context is then told to print itself.

The problem is that Ghostscript's rendering is driven by the initial device setup, because Ghostscript is not in charge of the printer device. Basically Ghostscript can't change the device setup so it has to alter the way the input is rendered to match the initial configuration.

I would have expected that Ghostscript would scale and potentially rotate the content so that it fits on the media available in the printer's default configuration.

You still haven't been totally clear about the problem; does your printer have both portrait and landscape media installed ? Are you expecting that portrait pages are printed on portrait media and landscape pages on landscape media ? Or is there some other problem ?

I can definitively say that Ghostscript's mswinpr2 device will not select different media, it will only use the default media.

[much later edit]
I don't know if its the same problem (or the same poster), but [this](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=699185) might be relevant.

Comment: that is exactly the problem, no matter what I do - I am always getting the printing in portrait (which is the printer default I guess). what are my options besides using the mswinpr2 if I want the command to work on windows devices?

Comment: Don' specify the printer in the OutputFile, leave off the switch. When you print Windows will offer you the pritn dialog. Select the printer, and configure it to have landscape media. See if that works. Ghostscript doesn't have any other devices for driving specifically Windows printers. If the printer handles any of PDF, PostScript, PCL, PCL-XL or XPS then Ghostscript can output those, which you could then send direct to the printer.